# Saving all open matplotlib figures in one file at once

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save an arbitrary number of matplotlib figures that I have already created into 1 file(PDF?). 
Is there a way to do it with one command?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

MatPlotLib currently supports [saving multiple figures to a single pdf file](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file). An implementation that uses this functionality would be:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def multipage(filename, figs=None, dpi=200):
    pp = PdfPages(filename)
    if figs is None:
        figs = [plt.figure(n) for n in plt.get_fignums()]
    for fig in figs:
        fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
    pp.close()
```

---

### Example Usage

First create some figures,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(10))

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(-np.arange(3, 50), 'r-')
```

By default `multipage` will print all of the open figures,

```
multipage('multipage.pdf')
```

The only *gotcha* here is that all figures are rendered as vector (pdf) graphics. If you want your figure to utilize raster graphics (i.e. if the files are too large as vectors), you could use the `rasterized=True` option when plotting quantities with many points. In that case the `dpi` option that I included might be useful, for example:

```
fig3 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.random.randn(10000), 'g-', rasterized=True)

multipage('multipage_w_raster.pdf', [fig2, fig3], dpi=250)
```

In this example I have chosen to only print `fig2` and `fig3`.

Comment: What if I didn't explicitly assign the figure to a variable? I would like to do something like multipage('name.pdf',all open figures)

Comment: I modified the `multipage` function so that it prints all open figures by default, using the `plt.get_fignums` function.

Comment: Great, thanks. Final question: is there a way to put several figures on 1 page?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that exactly. Most people would use `pyplot.subplot` to place multiple axes on a single figure, then print that figure like normal (i.e. to a 'page').

Comment: This was really helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thats a pretty usefull function for me. Thanks! However, you were not using the "dpi" argument. I guess it should read: `fig.savefig(pp, dpi=dpi, format='pdf')`